# Python Dataframe Duplicates Removal based on combination of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, data-preprocessing

I have a pandas dataframe that contains duplicates, but not regular duplicates you can remove by using simple `df.drop_duplicates`. For example when combining columns 1 and 2, for the purpose of my work, `AB` and `BA` are the same, and the 5th row should be eliminated.

```
1 2
---
A B ===> AB
C D
E F
G H
B A ===> BA
I J
K L
```

I want to remove duplicates keeping only one of the first rows. This would lead to:

```
1 2
---
A B
C D
E F
G H
I J
K L
```

cannot figure out how to do that. any help would be appreciated.

Update: (adding another column with numbers)

```
1 2  3
-------
A B 0.2 ===> AB
C D 0.1
E F 0.0
G H 0.5
B A 0.2 ===> BA
I J 0.3
K L 0.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'1': {0: 'A', 1: 'C', 2: 'E', 3: 'G', 4: 'B', 5: 'I', 6: 'K'}, 
        '2': {0: 'B', 1: 'D', 2: 'F', 3: 'H', 4: 'A', 5: 'J', 6: 'L'},
        '3': {0: 0.2, 1: 0.1, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.2, 5: 0.3, 6: 0.6}
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out = df.loc[~df[['1','2']].apply(sorted, axis=1).duplicated()]
print(out)

   1  2    3
0  A  B  0.2
1  C  D  0.1
2  E  F  0.0
3  G  H  0.5
5  I  J  0.3
6  K  L  0.6
```

Above solution assumes that you want to get rid of "duplicates" based on column `1` and `2`. However, if you want to look for "duplicates" on the entire df including col `3`, you'll need to convert all values to the same dtype (i.e. strings) first. So, in that case, you might do:

```
out = df.loc[~df.astype(str).apply(sorted, axis=1).duplicated()]
print(out)

   1  2    3
0  A  B  0.2
1  C  D  0.1
2  E  F  0.0
3  G  H  0.5
5  I  J  0.3
6  K  L  0.6
```

N.B. This will not affect the dtype of col `3` in the actual result of course; it still contains `float` values.

Comment: @Kiarash: you're welcome. If the answer offers a solution to your problem, please consider accepting it to close the question.

Comment: So... I add a third column that contains only decimal numbers, and now I get this error: "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'". Is there any way to get around it?

Comment: I take it this new column is not part of the duplicate check, right? If that assumption is correct, use: `df.loc[~df[['1','2']].apply(sorted, axis=1).duplicated()]`. I.e. only select columns `1` and `2` (not `3`). (Updated the answer accordingly.)

Comment: Perfect, the second recommendation works well and without changing the nature of col 3. Thanks again.